# Orchard - Text Field Fall Back Values

Tags: c#, content-management-system, orchardcms

Without actually creating a custom field, is there currently a way to set fall back values for text fields in Orchard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You need to either add that feature to the existing text field and contribute your patch, or create your own field.